# Translating document to multiple languages?

Tags: microsoft-word, language, translation

My question is what's the common approach when it comes to having the same document in multiple languages to keep integrity between versions and changes, as well as format.

I have to translate it myself, but having 1 document for each language seems a waste and a pain if you have to modify many of them.

I usually use MS Word but I'm not limited to this.

Comment: This is a really interesting question, but, it may require too much opinion and is therefore off topic (although +1). If it does get closed, remember, SU has chat rooms for this type of topic :)